# How to check adb commands executed on an Android device without executing them?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, adb, shell, logging

In my city recently *smart benches* were added to some parks. They have WiFi, heating, cooling, wireless charging and USB ports.

They're really cool and stylish, but when I plug my phone in to charge it they ask for the ADB key, which makes me think it is executing some malicious code.

**Is there a way to see what are the benches doing to your phone over ADB without actually running the commands?**

I have access to a Windows 7 laptop and an Android 5.1.1 device.

Comment: Asking for ADB almost _guarantees_ trouble. The common form here in China is installing a few apps which then shows ads and such. Get a dummy device (or back up and flash a ROM) to test it out.

Comment: @AndyYan But how would I know what did it do? For example if it steals files from my phone, how would I see the ADB log saying what it exactly did using ADB?

Comment: That's something I'd like to know too - upvoted for awareness.